# Unable to install open CV in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, opencv

I am trying to install openCv for learning purpose and then using it for OCR(Optical Character Recognition) but i am unable to install it in Ubuntu 12.04

I am following [this link](http://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/install-opencv-2-4-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) and able to carry upto step of downloading ffmpeg but while configuring it getting following error

```
ERROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found
```

I tried to [install libmp3lame](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26142/trouble-installing-codecs-libx264-and-libmp3lame) following this link but get this error again when configuring ffmpeg

```
ERROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found
```

Comment: Don't follow a link.  It's in repository.  Just use apt-get.

Comment: its not working, apt-get install libmp3lame, giving error E: Invalid operation libmp3lame

Comment: Not lame, opencv.  I have it installed on 12.04 via apt-get install python-opencv and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

To install OpenCV using the terminal on Ubuntu:

```
$ su -
# apt-get update
# apt-get install build-essential
# apt-get install libavformat-dev
# apt-get install x264 v4l-utils ffmpeg
# apt-get install libcv2.3 libcvaux2.3 libhighgui2.3 python-opencv \
   opencv-doc libcv-dev libcvaux-dev libhighgui-dev
```

http://namhuy.net/1205/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu.html